# Playing anamorphic video in chromecast

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I've got basic basic load and playback application running on the chromecast using the chrome api.
I've used the receiver.html from googles githib codesamples, and modified the chrome api sender sample to make a MediaLoadRequest.
It works fine, but the receiver seems to scale the video playback window to maximise the size.
This is fine , but some of the clips i want to play are anamorphic, ie they are 768x576 pixels 4:3 aspect ratio, but to display correctly should be rendered at 16:9 aspect ratio such as 1920x1080.

Is there some way i can interrogate the video properties in the receiver, and then modify the playback window, (via the CSS i guess)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The receiver uses the HTML5 video tag to play media. So something like this should work:

```
<script>
  var video = document.querySelector('video'),
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function(ev){

    var width = video.videoWidth
    var height = video.videoHeight;

  },false);
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the video element contains no metadata. The implementer will need to get the metadata elsewhere.